# Horizontal scroll in table cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following peculiar problem. Lets start with a code snippet:

```
...
<td>
   <div class="scrollable">...</div>
   ...other cell content...
</td>
...
```

Now I want the table render as if the `div.scrollable` wouldn't take any horizontal space (i.e. the `div.scrollable` doesn't push on the right side of the table), but show the horizontal scrollbar (on the `div.scrollable`, not on the whole cell) if the `div.scrollable` is wider then the containing cell. Is that possible to do via CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: whats does your css look like?

Comment: It is possible, what have you tried? Look at the css overflow property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to Pricey as his jsfiddle example answers the question, but to have the answer with the code here, I attach it bellow:

```
...
<style type="text/css>
  .mytable {
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .scrollable{
    overlow-y: auto;
  }
</style>
...
<table class="mytable">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="scrollable">...</div>
   other content...
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful please consider up voting it and if it gave you a solution then mark it as the answer, it helps everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Using your basic example you would likely need a set width on the `td` and to use `overflow` and `overflow-y`. `overflow-y` is CSS3 only but you didn't specify IE8 and below.

**EDIT** sorry you also need `display:block;` on the `td`

```
td { display: block; width: 50px; } 
.scrollable { overflow: scroll; overflow-y:hidden; }
```

**UPDATE:**
See the jsfiddle example, notice the 100% width on the table and the fixed layout.. thats to stop the example from just adding a horizontal scroll to the viewport and carrying on.
http://jsfiddle.net/MMeTe/4/

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that I don't want to set a specific width on a cell to let it accommodate the other content.

Comment: Ok well kinda need to see what your using it for i.e. if the table has a set width or if you want it fluid to the view port? then maybe you should apply a class to this specific `td` and set a % width on it? because your `td` will just resize to accommodate its contents.. alternatively add a wrapper around `scrollable`, and apply a width to the wrapper.

Comment: Say the table takes 80% of the viewport width and the scrollable div inside has a fixed width 500px (as an example). In this case, the scrollable div should have horizontal scrollbar only if 80% of the viewport is lower than 500px, otherwise the div should be fully visible.

Comment: My jsfiddle example answers your original question, so take a look at that. Your separate question about disabling the scroll when the table can accommodate the scrollbar div, is likely going to require a constant javascript check to see if the table has resized.. OR to set a media query to set a width condition on the view port and apply overriding styles.

Comment: Something like this maybe `@media screen and (min-width: 500px){ .scrollable { overflow: hidden; } }` but I haven't tried it, but you get the idea, just search for more info on the web about media queries.

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for. So the trick is that the table must have `table-layout: fixed`. Thanks Pricey!

Comment: @baa2w You should mark this answer as correct if it answers your question :)